# mono nunit test using WebClient receives ConnectFailure Exception

Tags: exception, https, mono, nunit, webclient

I'm trying to unit test some basic System.Net.WebClient code to download a string using an HTTPS endpoint.  It seems that using HTTPS from within the NUnit test fails no matter what.  I can use HTTP within the NUnit test without issue.  I can run the HTTPS code in a Console application without issue.

Here's the code...

```
        [Test()]
        public void TestWebclientHttp()
        {
            using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                string data = wc.DownloadString("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=alvis%20court&sensor=true");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);
            }           
        }

        [Test()]
        public void TestWebClientHttps()
        {
            using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                string data = wc.DownloadString("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=alvis%20court&sensor=true");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }
```

Here's the stack trace...

```
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:828 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:836 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:1433 
  at System.Net.WebClient.ReadAll (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.Object userToken) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:866 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataCore (System.Uri address, System.Object userToken) [0x0000a] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.6/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs:246
```

Development Environment...

- Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Mono develop 2.8.5
- Mono runtime 2.10.6

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Security#WebRequest.Create_.28.22https:.2F.2Fwww.anywhere.com.22.29.3B_throws_an_exception

Answer (score 1):

Mono does not ship with any trusted root certificate by default.

You can install them yourself using `mozroot` or, just for testing (**not** for production), [allow any](http://www.mono-project.com/UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully) SSL certificate to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had already read that article and don't think it applies.  The HTTPS code works fine in a mono console app.  It just doesn't work in the unit test.